# Will DFRS support a lot of data over a WAN?

Tags: network-share, windows-server-2016, distributed-filesystems

I have a server in our home location that houses many of our engineers. This location has Comcast fiber 100 up and down. Internally, the network here is much faster than that. This location has Server 2016 Datacenter, and a lot of extra power.

I have a remote location with some engineers that directly access some file shares at the home location. The continuing complaint is slowness. Some files take over 30 minutes to open. This site has Cox cable. Lets say 180/20. The server here is 2016 Standard, and is appropriately sized.

The sites are connected with a hardware VPN. In testing lowering the encryption settings to their lowest did not change the speed. We upgraded the main site to the fiber listed above. It helped slightly, but the connections were still slow. I've troubleshot with Comcast, and their response was HQ will get 100 at the firewall, but after that it is out of their hands. The end users must work on these files either on their computers, or over the network. Virtualizing their CAD work is not supported.

To resolve this, we're looking at 2 options:

1. Guaranteed 100 mpbs between the sites. This would probably solve it, but it is very expensive.
2. Setup the file share as DFRS and sync between the sites. The remote location has a server that could do this with a hardware upgrade. The file share is 1.5TB, with perhaps 20GB of churn per day.

I've not setup DFRS before. Is this something that it could do, and well?
If not, do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: What sort of SMB response times are you getting?  Look at performance counter "Avg. sec/Data Request", or packet captures with Wireshark's Statistics > Service Response Times > SMB2.

Comment: What is the nature of the file size and access pattern?  Opening a  gigabyte file, or thousands of small files, may be acceptable over a gigabit LAN, but terrible over a 10 Mbit WAN.